# ViewController not responding to didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My view controller is not responding to `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`, despite that I have added following in my code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    [self.popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    ... My Custom Code...   
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: One thing I just noticed that my controller class is a subclass of NSObject and not a subclass of UIViewController. I cannot change this hierarchy. Still there is any way out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't inherit from UIViewController (which is unfortunate), you can use [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDevice/beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Then register to start receiving [`UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW38) notifications.

Answer (score 2):

If your UIViewController is a child in some root view then IB does not add it as a child controller to the root controller by default. The easiest way to address this is to modify your root controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    [self addChildViewController:(UIViewController*) self.yourChildController];
}
```

This should do the trick. Now your child controller will be receiving both:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

and

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer here (more accurately the answer to the linked question) is that you need to call

```
[super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
```

in your subclass implementation of the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method. For example:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    // Then your code...
}
```

This is not mentioned in the apple documentation but caused some serious and unexplained problems for me when omitted...