# didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation not firing when rotating?

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ViewController not responding to didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860714/viewcontroller-not-responding-to-didrotatefrominterfaceorientation)

I'm having trouble with the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method not firing in one of my viewcontroller subclasses.

I have an iPad app w/ UISplitViewController as the main view. On the Detail side, I'm using a "hidden" (no toolbar,navbar) navigation controller for lazy view switching. The ViewController I'm wanting to catch didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation on is two levels deep in the navcontroller hierarchy. (None of this should make a difference, but I'm including this info in case there's some particular case that I don't know about)

I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

// This doesn't work. :(
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"Rotate Go!");
}
```

The view rotates just fine, but didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation never fires.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a uitabbar? Because if you are, you should create a uitabbar class and implement the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" at this class as well, so that all other controllers receive the rotation message.

Comment: Nope. I'm using a UISplitViewController, with a UIToolbar and UINavigationController (with the toolbar hidden, so different views share the other toolbar). But no UITabBar...

Comment: According to apple, your  UISplitViewController must be the root view in your application window. You can experience some weirdness if thatbis not the case. Check this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734016/uisplitviewcontroller-doesnt-autorotate

Comment: My `UISplitViewController` is the root view of the window. I'm making sure to return YES to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` from all of my subviews. The actual rotation works fine, its just that `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` is never called.

Comment: So, just a couple more question just to make it more clear. Are your controller extending any class other than `UIViewController`? Are you pushing your `UIViewController` or just adding the controller view as a subview of another controller? your are returning YES at `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, but is this method really getting called when you rotate or just the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`?

Comment: I have a `DetailViewController` (subclass of `UIViewController`) as the Detail side of the `UISplitViewController`. Rather than swapping out detail views, which gave me problems, I'm taking the lazy way out by having a `UINavigationController` on `DetailViewController`, with both the toolbar and navigation bar hidden. I'm pushing my other classes (which are all `UIViewController` subclasses with their own XIBs) onto the UINavigation stack to handle all changing of the detail views.

Comment: (continued) I am definitely returning YES to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in all subclasses, as they rotate just fine. But `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` never fires. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never did figure out why the events were not firing, but I did figure out a workaround:

In the two `UISplitViewController` delegate methods, `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` and `splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:`, I'm detecting whether or not my view is visible, and then doing my rotation logic here.

Answer (score 5):

If your UIViewController is a child in some root view then IB does not add it as a child controller to the root controller by default. The easiest way to address this is to modify your root controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    [self addChildViewController:(UIViewController*) self.yourChildController];
}
```

This should do the trick. Now your child controller will be receiving both:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

and

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

messages.

Comment: Thanks! This just fixed a problem that I had with UISplitViewController not getting rotational events.